# Can I use lava rock as a substitute for sponge rock for my Hawaii's Anthurium?

Tags: containers, potting-soil

I have a Hawaii's Anthurium, and the instructions say to plant it in a pot with 1 part peat moss and 2 parts perlite or sponge rock. I have lava rock. Would it be ok for me to plan the Hawaii's Anthurium in 1 part peat moss and 2 parts lava rock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s completely OK. Anthurium is a hardy plant and doesn’t really care about the soil’s subtle volcanic undertones